# Make background img 100% width while keeping content container another set width

Tags: css, width, fullscreen

So I'm trying to make the background image for one of my divs spread the full width of my screen while keeping the content in my div set at a certain width.

I've tried overflow:visible , min-width:100% , max-width:100% and none of these options seem to be working correctly. I'm unsure if it is because I've set the background image by overriding the original through CSS or what.

Since my webpage is not live yet, I've linked an image [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz8rl.png) to help explain.

The place I'm trying to put the rule to make the background image go full width is under [#content-core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuSrs.png) with max-width:100% only to have all of the content go full width instead of just the background image.

Any help would be much appreciated and if you need more information please ask. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your html along with any css you currently have?

Comment: I recommend you to put your code in here with the proper Code formatting so we can help you properly. A lot of people won't bother to click the image link.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to nest your content inside a container  div that you'll set to 100%.

```
.mycontainer {
 Width:100%;
} 

.mycontent {
Width:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, then  are overthinking this,

Simply use a main container with the CSS

```
background-image: url('example.com/img.png');
```

attribute and insert a different div in it with your content.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pqa8m9db/)